# AWS Disaster recovery together with backup and storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, high-availability, disaster-recovery

I have an implementation of hybrid AWS setup where I have an on-prem hadoop cluster and also replication enabled towards an AWS setup with similar hadoop cluster running at low capacity for disaster recovery. This is an active active disaster recovery setup in AWS. Is it still recommended to take backups for data that is stored on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it still recommended to take backups for data that is stored on AWS?

Not clear what AWS services you're referring to

Well, let's say you have an S3 bucket only bound to us-east-1 and that region becomes unavailable... You can't access your data. Therefore, it's encouraged to replicate to another region. However S3 supposedly has several 9's of availability, and if an AWS service is down in a major region, it's probably expected that a good portion of the internet is in-accessible, not only your data

Comment: Lets say it is a hadoop cluster running on EC2 instances backed by EBS storage which acts as a disaster recovery with active active setup in reference to onprem cluster. The data is being replicated from onprem setup to AWS setup at realtime for the data in database. Do we still need another backup process to be running on AWS data (which indeed is replicated from onprem databases). Logically, I dont see a reason why we need a backup again, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Your EBS volumes are not persistent. You should store long term data in S3 or Glacier